# Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 532

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/monitors/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

In my local system working fine but i move to the server i got this error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to make sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error that I solved by renaming the `Error` class to `Errors` in `application/controllers/Errors.php`. In `config/routes.php` I changed the class name accordingly:

```
$route['404_override'] = "errors/page_missing";
```

Comment: Thanx @Gfy, this is very useful method for resolve this error !